# Is there a way to see Javascript errors as a popup or notification in Edge Chromium

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, chromium

Traditional browsers such as Chrome and IE have mechanisms to see Javascript errors as either a notification implemented through a plugin in the case of Chrome and as a popup in the case of IE. However, in the newly introduced Edge Chromium browser, I was not able to figure out such a mechanism. Therefore please enlighten me should such mechanism be available in Edge Chromium, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's no browser built-in approach to achieve this, but you can use extensions to achieve this in Edge Chromium. As Edge Chromium uses the same rendering engine as Chrome, you can use the same plugin which is used in Chrome.

For example, I find [JavaScript Errors Notifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/javascript-errors-notifie/jafmfknfnkoekkdocjiaipcnmkklaajd) can achieve what you want. You can click on "Add to Chrome" to install this extension in Edge Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

I used this extension regularly, but it was pulled from the chrome store, so I took it on to get it republished.

This extension is rebuilt and republished again here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/javascript-errors-notifie/lplhclpeegjedapdliokcacmphgcnlnd?hl=en&authuser=0, the github for it is here https://github.com/coinzdude/javascript-errors-notifier and you can read about the journey here https://github.com/barbushin/javascript-errors-notifier/issues/101